# ibase_fetch_assoc: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: max, firebird, execution, interbase

I created this code to get an Interbase database, the total sales of a particular day:

```
 <?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
include("sql.php");
//Recibo los datos
$dia='21';
if( isset( $_POST['dia'] ) )
{
    $dia=$_POST["dia"];
}
$mes='07';
if( isset( $_POST['mes'] ) )
{
    $mes=$_POST["mes"];
}
$an='2014';
if( isset( $_POST['ano'] ) )
{
    $an=$_POST["ano"];
}
conectar();

//consulta las Ventas del Corte Actual
$sql="SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN VENTAS.tipo_documento = 'FAC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Facturas, SUM(CASE WHEN VENTAS.tipo_documento = 'DEV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Devoluciones, SUM(CASE WHEN VENTAS.tipo_documento = 'FAC' THEN ventas.total_lineas ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN VENTAS.tipo_documento = 'DEV' THEN ventas.total_lineas ELSE 0 END) as Facturado FROM VENTAS WHERE (EXTRACT(DAY FROM VENTAS.fecha_emision) = $dia) AND (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM VENTAS.fecha_emision) = $mes) AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM VENTAS.fecha_emision) = $an) AND ventas.temporal = 'F'";
//echo $sql;
$p_sql = ibase_prepare($sql);
$result = ibase_execute($p_sql) or die(ibase_errmsg());
if ($result){
    $row = ibase_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['FACTURADO'];
}
?>
```

But i got the error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in line 28...
Line 28: $row = ibase_fetch_assoc($result);
Then, I added this line:

```
set_time_limit(60);
```

and I get the same error, I want the script I have such a long life, in what way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with larger value or

you can enable it in php.ini

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time